# MVP. How to pass data between models?

Tags: android, model, mvp

I'm learning `MVP` structure and I trying to figure out:

- **How to pass data between models?**

Each model represents one action and if I need to send data from one
   model to another one, how can I properly make it? Should I pass data
   through presenter, like

```
firstModel -> commonPresenter -> secondModel
```

OR

send data between models, like

`firstModel -> secondModel?`

And what if these models interact with different presenters?

Answer (score 0):

The Model View Presenter pattern, like most architectural patterns, is quite open to experimentation. The important thing to keep in mind is to separate the View from the domain logic and data handling.

Particularly in Android, it's useful to keep the code as far as possible from Framework specific classes like Activities and Fragments.

In my experience, it's best to let Models communicate amongst themselves, as Observers of each other. The same goes for Views and Presenters, or, in general, any component in the same architectural layer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to convert your Domain models to your Ui models in presenter so you have to call a method or a constructor like this in presenter:

```
ModelOne modelOne = new ModelOne(modelTwo);
```

please consider DRY principals and do NOT assign each field in presenter itself like this

```
modelOne.title = modelTwo.title;
modelOne.id = modelTwo.id;
```

but if you want convert a Domain layer model to another Domain layer model you have to do it in other layers. read this for more info:
http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/

"the presenter communicates with model layer, converts the data to UI friendly format, and updates the view"
also you can find above sentence in this link: 
http://iyadagha.com/using-mvp-ios-swift/